# Homebrew: Rollback from Python 3.7 to Python 3.6.5.x?

Tags: homebrew, python

A `brew upgrade` upgraded my system Python to Python 3.7. Unfortunately, Python 3.7 breaks other software I need to use (including but not limited to Ansible). I imagine these problems will be worked out in the next week or so, but in the meantime, I'd like to rollback to Python 3.6.5.x

A `brew info python` shows that previous versions are still installed and not purged:

```
➜ brew info python
python: stable 3.7.0 (bottled), HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5 (4,825 files, 100.8MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2018-03-31 at 20:21:57
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1 (4,788 files, 99.9MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2018-06-20 at 16:00:26
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0 (4,869 files, 103.3MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2018-07-01 at 19:30:37
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python.rb
```

Various `brew link` and `brew install` commands that are suggested by other sites don't seem to work:

```
➜ brew link python@3.6.5
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.6.5
➜ brew link python@3.6.5_1
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.6.5_1
➜ brew install python@3.6.5
Error: No available formula with the name "python@3.6.5" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: For those who don't have 3.6.5_1 installed, there is a way to get it via brew: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51125014/760905

Comment: There is a python version 3.7.1. maybe that fixes your problems.

Comment: For those landing here looking for a way to use an arbitrary older python version, try https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv (which you can install with brew)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you still have the previous versions available, you can just use

```
brew switch python 3.6.5_1
```

Comment: Give me a couple of months I'll be ready to switch to 3.7. When that day comes, how do I undo this `brew switch ...` command to get back to 3.7?

Comment: How does this differ to creating a virtual environment attached to Python 3.6.5?

Comment: @jmh for some reason my 3.6.5 virtual environments broke when I used Homebrew to update to 3.7, and I haven't quite figured out why. Of course, one of the reasons I made virtual environments in the first place was to avoid that issue. Switching back fixed it. Since nothing in 3.7 is critical for me, I'm just sticking with 3.6.5 for the moment.

Comment: I realized that the reason for the above is that Python's built-in venv creates symlinks, which break when going from Python 3.6.x to 3.7.x. Creating venvs with `python3 -m venv --copies venv` copies the Python files instead of creating symlinks, which prevents them from breaking when upgrading your Python version.

Comment: `Error: python does not have a version "3.6.5_1" in the Cellar.
python installed versions: 3.7.0`

Comment: Self note: To create a virtualenv, use `python3 -m pip install virtualenv && python3 -m venv venv_name`

Comment: Once you've rolled back consider `brew pin python` to keep it there. This will prevent Homebrew from upgrading it when you do a `brew upgrade`.

Comment: Update: HomeBrew has removed the `switch` command, so this no longer will work. See [this link for the](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/339) discussion around removing the option

Answer (score 62):

If you don't have previous version to switch to, you can install **Python 3.6.5_1** from previous formula this way:

```
$ brew unlink python

$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```

If you are getting:

```
# --ignore-depeError: python contains a recursive dependency on itself:
  python depends on sphinx-doc
  sphinx-doc depends on python
```

...then run:

```
$ brew install --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```

...instead of the last command.

If then you will  get the following error when you do `pip3 install` after such installation:

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

...then a workaround may be to install its dependencies first (everything except `sphinx-doc`)

```
$ brew install pkg-config gdbm openssl readline sqlite xz
```

Notice that it needs `openssl` and **NOT** `openssl@1.1` which is a latest dependency in homebrew python 3.7.*.

Comment: I think it would be useful if you also explain what `brew unlink python` does.

Comment: Moreover, you should emphasize that this doesn't apparently remove your current Python 3.7 version, and that later you can switch back to it (using e.g. what is suggested [https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/329192/90775](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/329192/90775)).

Comment: If you get an issue about a recursive dependence, this can be bypassed by ignoring dependencies: `brew install --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb`.

Comment: If `--ignore-dependencies` doesn't work due to sphinx, comment out the dependency in sphinx and reinstall sphinx as described here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/01/30/macos-mojave-install-tensorflow-and-keras-for-deep-learning/

Comment: ```Error: python contains a recursive dependency on itself:
  python depends on sphinx-doc
  sphinx-doc depends on python```

Answer (score 14):

### Two options

**To recover a previously installed Python version:**

```
brew switch python 3.x.x_x # Ex. 3.6.5_1
```

Use `brew info python` to see what you have previously installed

**To make a clean install of Python 3.6.5 use:**

```
brew unlink python # If you have installed (with brew) another version of python
brew install --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```

### Long Answer

There are two formulas for installing Python with Homebrew: `python@2` and `python`.
The first is for Python 2 and the second for Python 3.

**Note:** You can find outdated answers on the web where it is mentioned `python3` as the formula name for installing Python version 3. Now it's just `python`!

By default, with these formulas you can install the latest version of the corresponding major version of Python. So, you cannot directly install a minor version like 3.6.

### Solution:

With `brew`, you can install a package using the address of the formula, for example in a git repository.

```
brew install https://the/address/to/the/formula/FORMULA_NAME.rb
```

Or specifically for Python 3

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/COMMIT_IDENTIFIER/Formula/python.rb
```

The address you must specify is the address to the last commit of the formula (python.rb) for the desired version.
You can find the commint identifier by looking at the history for homebrew-core/Formula/python.rb

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/master/Formula/python.rb

### Python > 3.6.5

In the link above you will not find a formula for a version of Python above 3.6.5.
After the maintainers of that (official) repository released Python 3.7, they only submit updates to the recipe of Python 3.7.

As explained above, with homebrew you have only Python 2 (python@2) and Python 3 (python), **there is no explicit formula for Python 3.6**.

Although those minor updates are mostly irrelevant in most cases and for most users, I will search if someone has done an explicit formula for 3.6.

Comment: https://github.com/sashkab/homebrew-python seems to do it

Comment: For 3.6, I tried to install from the URL and was getting the error 'Invalid usage: Installation of python from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported! `brew extract python` to a stable tap on GitHub instead'. I ended up using the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65308770/975592

Answer (score 4):

Following **Step #3: Downgrade Python 3.7 to Python 3.6 on macOS Mojave** here worked for me: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/01/30/macos-mojave-install-tensorflow-and-keras-for-deep-learning/

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily backdate `homebrew-core` and set the `HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE` variable to hold it in place:

```
cd `brew --repo homebrew/core`
git checkout f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558
export HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1
brew install python
brew install vim --with-python
```

I don't recommend permanently backdating homebrew-core, as you will miss out on security patches, but it is useful for testing purposes.

You can also extract old versions of homebrew formulae into your own tap (tap_owner/tap_name) using the `brew extract` command:

```
brew extract python tap_owner/tap_name --version=3.6.5
```

Comment: Making your own tap or finding someone who has automated maintaining the 3.6 and other series with updates is definitely the best way to go. If they do it properly you can have a fully qualified version and link it with `brew link python@3.6.x`. Though `pyenv` is another option as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have opted out of brew version and used [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/) to manage multiple Python versions.

Assuming you already have asdf installed:

```
brew unklink python
asdf plugin-add python
asdf install python 3.6.9 && asdf global python 3.6.9
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing on this page, adding to rinat.io's answer above: brew has undergone changes and extracting old formulas is a bit of a pain. Refer to this issue https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/635 for resolving any OpenSSL related issues with pip.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert on this, but had the same issue.  This is what worked for me:
`$ brew unlink python
$ brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python3
$ brew uninstall pipenv
then from https://www.python.org/downloads/ installed python 3.6.6
$ brew install pipenv`

Answer (score -1):

I could not find the correct solution to a similar problem of mine (with vim quitting unexpectedly) to quickly rollback to the previous version of python.

Here is the oneliner I often use. In this case, it would be:

> Disclaimer: some programs from brew manager may require other versions of python due to their own dependencies.

```
brew update && brew install python@3.6.5_1 && brew unlink python@3.7 && brew link python@3.6.5_1 --force && brew cleanup
```

Comment: That links to the newer python and removes the older one which is the opposite of the question

Comment: thanks, for pointing it out. my bad, spelling mistake.