# How to install Python 3.7 via homebrew on OS X

Tags: install, homebrew, python

I need to rollback my homebrew-managed python 3.8 to 3.7.

I have tried the approach from [Homebrew: Rollback from Python 3.7 to Python 3.6.5.x? - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329187/homebrew-rollback-from-python-3-7-to-python-3-6-5-x). So I unlinked 3.8, but my `python.rb` URL for 3.7 seems to be wrong. I used:

```
brew install --ignore-dependencies https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/eb6d8719c1880dd7c5d03a49c45ab40509fc2927/Formula/python.rb
```

and with this I get the following error:

"*Calling Non-checksummed download of python formula file from an arbitrary URL is disabled.*"

What is the correct command to install Python 3.7 via homebrew?

Comment: Did you try  brew install python@3.7?  Thats the formula for python 3.7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187812/homebrew-how-to-install-older-versions

Comment: @jmh Ups, that works perfectly! Thanks. I got too "distracted" by the above mentioned SO answer... If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to install python 3.7 is from Homebrew using the following command: `brew install python@3.7`

Comment: It's deprecated upstream.